# Session data crossover

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

There is a Java webapplication deployed in tomcat and Apache webserver.
There is only one tomcat instance in production and there is no concept of loadbalancer.
But, after introducing Apache webserver, User A is able to completely see User B s data, meaning, User B's session is accessed by User A.
The same code was working fine, when there was only tomcat instance, now on introducing Apache web server, we are facing this session data crossover issue.

//httpd.conf properties

```
worker.list=tomcat_lb,jkstatus

# Define a 'jkstatus' worker using status
worker.jkstatus.type=status

worker.tomcat_lb.type=lb
worker.tomcat_lb.balance_workers=tomcat_1
#worker.tomcat_lb.balance_workers=tomcat_1,tomcat_2

# Specifies whether requests with SESSION ID's
# should be routed back to the same #Tomcat worker.
worker.tomcat_lb.sticky_session=True
```

Comment: If you're not using load balancing, why have you configured it (with `type=lb`)?

Comment: Also, In web.xml. there is a configuration. Not sure, if this is causing the problem                                                                                           <filter>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
        <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

Comment: To avoid confusion, please add config details to your question instead of writing comments. Folks here will only be able to help you if you quote your configuration in a comprehensible way. So you connect Apache with Tomcat using `mod_jk`, right? Then show us the part of your `httpd.conf` containing the `JkMount` directives, add your complete `workers.properties` and maybe even Tomcat's `server.xml` file(s)...

Comment: The issue is resolved. I have added this line in httpd.conf                                           CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie                         Reference:http://www.softslate.com/blog/2011/07/apache-modcache-in-real-world.html